# How can i convert linux "date +%s" output to a more readable format in bash script

Tags: bash, datetime

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i="0"
startTime=`date -u +%s`
startTime=$[$startTime+$1+5]
echo ""
echo "##################"
echo "LAUNCHING REQUESTS"
echo "  COUNT:  $1 "
echo "  DELAY:  1 "
echo "  EXECUTION:  $startTime "
echo "##################"
echo ""

while [ $1 -gt "$i" ]
do
  i=$[$i+1]
  php avtestTimed.php $1 $2 $startTime &
  echo "QUEUEING REQUEST $i"
  sleep 1
done
```

so i want to convert $startTime into a UTC format

Comment: The `$[]` form is deprecated. Use `$(())` instead. Or you can drop the dollar sign and put the parentheses on the outside of the whole expression: `(( startTime += $1 + 5 ))` and `(( i++ ))`. Also, don't use backticks, use `$()`: `startTime=$(date -u +%s)`. It's more readable, can be easily nested and avoids potential difficult quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
date -d @$(($startTime-$1-5))
```

if you want to decode the first state of $startTime variable, or this:

```
date -d @$startTime
```

and, you can add `-u` argument to get the UTC time... %)

read the `man date`

Answer (score 1):

What format are you looking for? Simply executing date with -u Will give you a readable output format of UTC time, ie:

```
# date -u
Tue Nov 30 15:35:12 UTC 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-d` to pass `$startTime` back into `date` for processing, just prefix it with `@` so it is recognized as seconds since the epoch.

```
$ date -d @$startTime
```

Once you have that down you can change the output format. I would suggest looking at the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) or the info documentation of `date` for that. For UTC output you would use

```
$ date -d @$startTime -u
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have another variable

> startTimeHuman=$(date -u -R)

right next to where you set startTime.  This way you'd have both variants, one for doing math, and one for humans to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Got perl?

```
human_time=$(perl -e 'print scalar gmtime(shift)' $startTime)
```